# Spring Batch: Read from txt files and return all lines as a single String to the processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to read text from files in Spring Batch but i need all lines as a single String reaching the `.processor` and not line by line. I read about `.setRecordSeparatorPolicy` in `FlatFileItemReader`. Is there any other way to achieve this? Maybe another kind of reader or something? 
Any help would be really appreciated

```
public ItemStreamReader<String> stringReader() throws IOException {
    Resources[] resources.. // load files here
    MultiResourceItemReader<String> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<String>();
    reader.setResources(resources);
    reader.setDelegate(flatFileItemReader()); //sets FlatFileIteamReader

    return reader;
}

@Bean
public TaskletStep managerStep() throws Exception {
    return managerStepBuilderFactory.get("managerStep")
            .<String, String>chunk(6)
            .reader(stringReader())
            .processor(myProcessor()) //all lines as 1 String here per File
            .writer(doSomething())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: which version of java? is a Java8 solution ok? Then simply do: `processor(String.join(",", myProcessor())); //choose your own delimiter`

Answer (score 0):

The chunk processing model is designed for item oriented use cases. If you have a single item, I don't see any added value of using a chunk-oriented step. A simple tasklet is more appropriate.